# JSONObject to String Android

Tags: java, android, json

how can I convert a JSONObject like `"{hello1: hi, hello2: hey}"` to `"hello1: hi, hello2: hey"` without these brackets `{ }` ?

I know that there is a opportunity to use JSONObject.tostring but then I'll get a string with the brackets.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just do a substring or string replace.

**Pseudo** substring Example:

```
JSONObject a  = new JSONObject("{hello1: hi, hello2: hey}");
String b = a.toString().substring(1, a.toString().length() - 1);
```

**Pseudo** string replace Example:

```
JSONObject a  = new JSONObject("{hello1: hi, hello2: hey}");
String b = a.toString().replace("{", "");
String c = b.toString().replace("}", "");
```

Comment: you will need to spell `length` not `lenght` :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you actually want to do something more elaborate than your question suggests and you can make some assumptions about the JSON you'll be working with, you could do something like the following to get any output format you'd like.

```
JSONObject json  = new JSONObject("{hello1: hi, hello2: hey}");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String k : json.keys()) {
    sb.append(k);
    sb.append(": ").
    sb.append(json.getString(k));
    sb.append(", ")
}

// do something with sb.toString()
```

Then again, I might have read into this too much (in which case @ProgrammerXR's answer would do the trick).