# break JSON response from server using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using Volley library to POST data to the server and I have a JSON response from server which is shown below.

Right now I can access **"code"** and **status** easily.

The problem is I'm unable to access **"name"** and other properties of **"user"**.
I have tried the following questions but they didn't help me and maybe that's because I am very new to JSON and android.

[how to convert json object to string in android..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049582/how-to-convert-json-object-to-string-in-android)

[How to convert json object into string in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905996/how-to-convert-json-object-into-string-in-android)

[JSONObject to String Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933753/jsonobject-to-string-android)

[How to convert this JSON object into a String array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929603/how-to-convert-this-json-object-into-a-string-array)

Im using volley library, here is the code:

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
new Response.Listener<String>() {

@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {

JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
String code = jsonResponse.getString("status");

} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

}
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      error.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
     ) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        // the POST parameters:
                        params.put("name", userName);
                        params.put("email", userEmail);
                        params.put("password",userPass);
                        params.put("deviceIdentifier", deviceIdent);
                        params.put("deviceType", deviceI);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(postRequest);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the JSON objects first:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString);
if (response.has("data") {
   JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
   if (data.has("user") {
      JSONObject user = data.getJSONObject("user");
      String name = user.optString("name", "");
   }
}
```

Your response is built like this:

```
{ // JSONObject (lets call it response)
   "status": true, // boolean inside "response" JSONObject
   "code": 200, // int inside "response" JSONObject
   "data": { // JSONObject (lets call it data) inside "response" JSONObject
      [...], // Some more objects inside "data" JSONObject
      "user": { // JSONObject (lets call it user) inside "data" JSONObject
         [...], // Some more objects inside "user" JSONObject
         "name": "abc", // String inside "user" JSONObject
         [...], // Some more objects inside "user" JSONObject
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried to access the name like you said and faced and got the name but also faced this exception org.json.JSONException: No value for user .

Comment: Is there a "user" inside the response like shown in your question?

Comment: yes. it throws the exception when I try to insert the same record again.

Comment: Try my edited answer to make sure your JSONObjects exists